# nginx - error_page is ignored when I throw an error from try_files

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
error_page 502 =200 @proxy_down;
error_page 503 @maintenance;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://proxy;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location @proxy_down {
    root /path/to/folder/;
    try_files $uri =503;
}

location @maintenance {
    root /path/to/another/folder/;
    try_files /maintenance.html =503;
}
```

What I want to accomplish: normally I pass all requests to my reverse proxy. When proxy is for some reason down, so it throws 502, I want nginx to try to serve files from my local folder (with status 200), and if they're not found either, I want to return my *maintenance.html* file with status 503.

Unfortunately, this does not work. It just serves me the default nginx 503 page. Why is it so and how do I make it work?

What I'm doing right now is I do `try_files $uri @maintenance` and then in *@maintenance* location I do `return 503 "<literally the whole HTML page here>"`, but this is amazingly stupid. How do I serve a static file with a specific status code without hardcoding it into the conf file?

Comment: The main problem is that Nginx does not allow `error_page` to be nested. You could use `try_files $uri @maintenance;` in @proxy_down, if you can accept the maintenance page being returned with a 200 status code.